# Can the holy Qur'an be recited from English transliteration instead of Arabic text?

Tags: quran-recitation

I'm not that well versed with Arabic therefore I keep in making mistakes in pronunciation. Recently I came across an app where the entire the holy Qur'an is transliterated which makes it much easier (for me) to recite.

My concern is, is my recitation still valid if I read from the transliterated text instead of the Arabic text?

Answer (score 1):

Salam Femme,

my teacher always says to me in every day when I have difficulty in improving reading al-Quran. She always give an ayah, what Allah promises to us.

> "We have made this Qur'an easy as a reminder. Is there, then, any
>   who will take heed?" (Surah Al-Qamar (541: 17)

This verse is repeatedly mentioned 4 times in the Al-Qamar(17, 22, 32,40)

This repetition is a sign that God will not give trouble to anyone who wants to learn the Quran, especially reading and writing of the Qur'an. God's promise is evidenced by the emergence of various practical methods that facilitate Muslims to learn to read the Qur'an.

Through these methods, it can be said that there is no reason anymore
for Muslims to be able to read the Holy Quran.

So keep spirit in learn Al-Quran in Arabic version, Femme. There are so many old lady here still learning with spirit to read "aa ba taa" in this holy Quran. I never hesitate with their spirit to get Jannah and *fastabiqul khoirot*~ competing in goodness.

Comment: Jazzak Allah Khair sisters.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember dear Femme,

Ameerul mu'minin Abi Hafsa Umar ibnil khattab radhiallaahu anhu said he heard from our prophet Muhammad Sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam told,

> "**Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah), so each man will have what he intended.** Thus, he whose migration (hijrah) was to Allah and His Messenger, his migration is to Allah and His Messenger; but he whose migration was for some worldly thing he might gain, or for a wife he might marry, his migration is to that for which he migrated."
>
> > Sahih Muslim: Book on Government
> >
> > > In book reference: book 33; hadith 222

So, even when you are trying to recite Quran from transliteration, your intention may be counted.

But reciting from Transliteration might go pronouncing wrongly which, in worst case, might result in opposite meaning of what it was said in the original text.

So, you need to re-check with a scholar of what you learnt from a transliteration copy of Quran.

But remember, the rewards of reciting quran from the holy books seeing the arabic letters is greater than reciting by not seeing (I mean reciting from memory).

But there is another factor which we also cannot deny.
Hazrat Anas bin Malik Radhiallaahu ta'ala anhu said that our prophet Hazrat Muhammad Sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam said

> "**Seeking knowledge is a duty upon every Muslim**, and he who imparts knowledge to those who do not deserve it, is like one who puts a necklace of jewels, pearls and gold around the neck of swines"
>
> > Sunan Ibn Majah: Book of Sunnah
> >
> > > Arabic Reference: Book 1, Hadith 229

So, even though you cannot recite Quran in arabic or you are weak in reciting Quran, you need to keep trying to learn it from Learned person. You have to keep learning to recite Quran reasonably well so that you may pass the satisfaction of the scholars you might be learnt from.

**And Allaah ta'ala knows best.**

Answer (score 0):

The Arabic is better and if you try to learn Arabic you understand 'Ejaaz' of Quran more better.In general position language is not important and attending to Quran and use it in every moment of your life is very important.

```
إنا أنزلناه قرآنا عربيا لعلكم تعقلون  ﴿۲﴾
```

Comment: Please provide some references for your answer.